# display the count result using group_by to view

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

how to display the group_by result to view?

my controller:

```
public function filter_by_province($region="",$province=""){
$this->load->model('geoinfo');
$data['numberofmun']=$this->geoinfo->provinces_count($region,$province);
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('filter_result_province', $data);
}
```

my model:

```
public function provinces_count($region,$province){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('geo_data');
$this->db->where('region', urldecode($region));
$this->db->where('province',urldecode($province));
$this->db->group_by('municipal');
$query=$this->db->get();

$result=count('$query->num_rows()');
return $result; 

}
```

i don't know how to display the result to view.

i want the result like this

Municipal Name       |      Number of Records
Municipal 1          |             5
Municipal 2          |             2
Municipal 3          |             7
Municipal 4          |             7
Municipal 5          |             3

how to display like that in view

Answer (score 0):

I would say this will help you.

> model code

```
Public function provinces_count($region,$province){
$this->db->select(‘regoin’, count(municipal) AS municipal’);
$this->db->from('geo_data');
$this->db->where('region', urldecode($region));
$this->db->where('province',urldecode($province));
$this->db->group_by('municipal');
$result=$this->db->get();
return $result; 
}
```

> controller code

```
public function filter_by_province($region="",$province=""){
$this->load->model('geoinfo');
$data['numberofmun']=$this->geoinfo->provinces_count($region,$province);
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('filter_result_province', $data);
}
```

you can use foreach loop in view to display data

Comment: how to display the $result to view? do i need sa foreach to view the result? like for example <?php foreach($result as $row); ?>

Comment: you are missing one thing is that your model code should be you controller code and controller code should be your model code. exchange the code.

Comment: sorry..i mistaken my title..actually, the one i've put to model is actually my controller and my controller is the one i put it  on the model...i already edit the title